# HTML Table show when specific value on select menu is selected

Tags: javascript, html

on my html page, I have a select menu with a few options on it. When I select one option, I want the html to show a table that is related to that option.

How can I show the exact table when, for instance, I select Admin on the select menu? 
Then, when I select Engineering, it would hide the Admin Table and show the Engineering Table?

```
         <div class="controls">
             <select id="select01">
                <option id="admin">Admin</option>
                <option id="eng">Engineering</option>
             </select
          </div>

        <div style="display:none" id="admin">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
               <thead>
                 <tr>
                     <th>ADMIN</th>
                     <th>First Name</th>
                     <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Username</th>
                </tr>
               </thead>
              <tbody>
                  <tr>
                     <td>1</td>
                     <td>Mark</td>
                     <td>Otto</td>
                     <td>mdo</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
             </table>
           </div>


        <div style="display:none" id="eng">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
               <thead>
                 <tr>
                     <th>Engineering</th>
                     <th>First Name</th>
                     <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Username</th>
                </tr>
               </thead>
              <tbody>
                  <tr>
                     <td>1</td>
                     <td>Mark</td>
                     <td>Otto</td>
                     <td>mdo</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
             </table>
           </div>
```

Thank you.

Comment: HINT: IDs are supposed to be unique in HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED**

Based on your code:

```
$(function () { 
    $("#admin").show();

    $("#select01").on("change", function () {
        $(".myClass").hide();
        $("div[id='" + $(this).val() + "']").show();
    });
});
```

But first, fix this:

```
<select id="select01">
    <option value="admin">Admin</option>
    <option value="eng">Engineering</option>
</select>
```

and this:

```
<div class="myClass" id="admin">
...
</div>

<div class="myClass" id="eng">
...
</div>
```

And add this to your stylesheet:

```
.myClass
{
    display: none;
}
```

Tested: http://jsfiddle.net/Du7dJ/2/

Comment: I would add some class to the divs and shorten down the code, but it works the same way.

Comment: why add classes to the divs?

Comment: Doing that it would save you the work of hiding/showing per IDs. You could just select the whole bunch by the Class.

Comment: I've updated the answer. It doesn't look very useful now, but if you start adding tables (divs) in the future, it'll save you coding.